# RethinkDB filtering speed

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

In my testing on rethinkdb, i have inserted 14 millions data into a table.

Sample data inserted -

```
{"name": "jason" , "id" : "1", "email": "jason@gmail.com", ...}
```

id was generated by counter of 14 millions

When i tried to filter the table by using this query

```
r.db("test").table("test_table").filter({"id":"10000"})
```

This query takes about 13 seconds to return a table row.

Is there any faster ways to filter the table and return a table row that we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` doesn't use an index, it just applies the predicate you give it to every row.  You can use `get` to get an element by primary key (so `r.table('test_table').get(10000)` in your case), or `getAll`/`between` to get by a secondary index.

Comment: what if the the key 'id' is not primary key, it is an inserted key?

Comment: Then you need an index on it to make querying it fast.  You can read more about secondary indexes at https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/ .